# does hudson ci support parallel builds on the same machine?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

My project takes a long time to build (~3h) and the compiler is not making effective use of the quad-core cpu.
The project also requires multiple builds of each version to support different configurations.

Can hudson support building several instances of the same project simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature continues to be marked as 'Beta' as we are aware that there are some situations in which you might find a conflict using concurrent builds eg maven builds might cause issues, blocking downstream builds should help

Essentially, if you are able to run these jobs in parallel then you should have no problems with the feature.

That said, if you are able to use the latest Maven 3 support (in Hudson 2.1.0) you could use the experimental threading support to parallelize your build

Comment: These jobs are able to run in parallel, but each will require their own workspace. Will this method allow for this or are they expected to share the workspace?

Comment: From the hudson docs: If you use a custom workspace and enable this option, all your builds will run on the same workspace, thus unless a care is taken by your side, it'll likely to collide with each other. Otherwise, even when they are run on the same node, Hudson will use different workspaces to keep them isolated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though it's still marked as beta, just have a look at the project settings, near the top should be the entry you're looking for ("Execute concurrent builds if necessary (beta) " You need to have enough build processors configured on that machine and make sure multiple builds don't interfere with each other (which may be the hardest part)

Comment: Is there a way to enable parallel support on build slaves?  For instance, we have a 12-core Mac Pro slave for our iOS builds, and it would be nice to have it parallelizable as well.